# How to catch exceptions from function that has been passed as an argument to another function

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I have a library that makes calls to an API.

I want to be able to retry the call with different credentials due to some limitations of the API that I am calling.

I have everything inside a function that the library function is passed to.

however, when I try to catch any exception from the call no exceptions are caught and I just end up with the code exiting and a stack trace.

the code looks like below

```
import the_library

def making_the_call(api_call):
    try:
        api_call()
    except TheKeyExceptionIamLookingFor:
        # change creds and redo the call
    except OtherExceptionsICareAboutAndExpect:
        # Do other stuff to handle

making_the_call(the_library.some_api_call(the_args))
```

This is running in aws lambda so I don't know if that is what is helping cause this issue.

I have run similar code in the python console and it catches the exception just fine from a passed function with arguments but this code just exits and gives me a stack trace even showing the exact exception I am looking for and planning to catch.

Comment: It looks like you're calling `some_api_call` and then passing the result into `making_the_call` as an argument.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh that thought had crossed my mind however my google foo is failing me on how to pass the arguments separately, hence I did it this way, could you give me an example or a resource to go read on how to do it correctly?

Comment: This is actually a pretty good question with a simple straightforward answer. I wasn't expecting that when I started reading it. Good job OP.

Comment: have you tried `except the_library.ExceptionYouAreLookingFor:` ? I had a similar issue before, where I tried to catch a `ConnectionError` but it wouldn't return.  Turns out I had catch `Requests.ConnectionError` as it was it's own special exception object in the imported module.

Comment: @Idlehands I am actually importing the specific error from the library
`from the_library.api_errors import TheExceptionIamLookingFor` so that wasn't the case this time, but it's a good thing to point out for anyone who looks at this in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pass everything seperately you would do

```
def make_call(api_call, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        return api_call(*args, **kwargs)
    except SomeException:
        # change args and kwargs
        return make_call(api_call, *args, **kwargs)

make_call(the_library.some_api_call, 'apple', 1, 2, 3)
```

Notice the lack of `()` after `some_api_call`. Inside `make_call` `args` will be a `list` and `kwargs` (keyword arguments) will be a `dict`